# WebAPI OData v4 - Using a class to represent an action's parameters

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata, odata-v4

I want to add an action to my OData controller. I'll be calling this action with the request body matching the following structure, and with the following validation requirements:

```csh
public class PublishModel
{
    [Required, EnumDataType(typeof(JobEventType))]
    public JobEventType Type { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(100)]
    public string ExternalRef { get; set; }

    public DateTimeOffset? DateTime { get; set; }
}
```

With a normal ApiController, I'd normally have my controller method simply take an argument of this type, and it'd work. With OData, it seems I have to implement my method using a ODataActionParameters argument.

I can't figure out how I'm supposed to tell OData that the body of the request should match the above. The closest I've got is to have it expect it in a parameter:

```csh
var pa = mb.EntityType<Edm.JobEvent>().Collection.Action("publish");
pa.ReturnsFromEntitySet<Edm.JobEvent>("jobevent");
pa.Parameter<PublishModel>("evt");
```

But this requires me to send

```csh
{"evt":{"type":"...","externalRef":"...","dateTime":"..."}}
```

When what I want to send is just

```csh
{"type":"...","externalRef":"...","dateTime":"..."}
```

I understand that I can just specify the properties of my class as individual parameters, but that'll be harder to maintain and I'll lose the data annotation validation. Is there a way to handle this?

Comment: Not from me, I'm afraid. I ended up creating an instance of the class with the data annotations, copying the parameters in, and manually validating. Messy.

Comment: Btw, I thought your first snippet is the correct one. Because the Odataparameters object expect your serialized object to be the value, while the "vet" is the key. Right?